Expectation of zigzag length in a sequence
A real number sequence $\ y_{1},\ y_{2},\ \ldots,\ y_{k}\ $ $\left(k \geq 2\right)$ is called a "zigzag" sequence if $\ y_{2} - y_{1},\ y_{3} - y_{2},\ \ldots,\ y_{k} - y_{k - 1}\ $ are all non-zero and alternate in sign:

Let $X_{1},\ X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}$ be independent and uniformly distributed random variables on the interval $\left[0,1\right]$.
Define $a\left(X_{1},\ X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}\right)$ as the maximum value of $k$ ( with $k \geq 2$ )

such that there exists an increasing integer index sequence $i_{1},\
   i_{2},\ldots, i_{k}$ making $X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_{k}}$ a
"zigzag" sequence.


Find the expected value of
$\ a\left(X_{1},\ X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ for $n \geq 2$.

What I've tried so far is to consider the relationship between $E_{n}$ and $E_{n - 1}$, but I'm not sure how to determine whether the added $X_{n}$ is gonna increase the $E$ or not.

We say that a sequence $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ has a local minimum at index $k$ if
\begin{cases}
x_{k-1}>x_{k}<x_{k+1}, &\text{when }k\in\{2,3,\dots, n-1\},\\
x_1<x_2, &\text{when }k=1,\\
x_{n-1}>x_n, &\text{when }k=n.
\end{cases}
The definition of local maximum at index $k$ is analogous.

Fact: $$a(X_1,X_2,…,X_n) = \#\{\text{local minima of $X$}\}+\#\{\text{local maxima of $X$}\}.$$ Proof: The values $(X_k)_{k=1,\dots,n}$ are almost surely distinct, so we can assume there are no repetitions. First we prove the $\ge$ inequality. Let $(j_1,\dots,j_m)$ and $(k_1,\dots,k_M)$  be the increasing sequences of indexes of local minima and local maxima respectively. Suppose that $j_1<k_1$, (the other case is analogous). Note that the sequence of indexes $(j_1,k_1,j_2,k_2,\dots)$ is increasing and its length is $m+M$. Since the subsequence $(X_{j_1},X_{k_1},X_{j_2},X_{k_2},\dots) $ of length $m+M$ is alternating, $a\ge m+M$.
To assess the $\le$ inequality, take a maximal sequence of indexes $(i_1,\dots,i_a)$ such that the subsequence $(X_{i_1},\dots,X_{i_a})$ is alternating. Suppose that $X_{i_1}>X_{i_2}$ (the other case is analogous). Eventually decrease every odd index (i.e. $i_1,i_3,\dots$) by $1$ until you reach a local maximum, and eventually increase every even index by $1$ until you reach a local minimum. We obtain a new increasing sequence $(i_1',\dots,i_a')$ of indexes such that the alternating sequence $(X_{i_1'},\dots,X_{i_a'})$ is made of local maxima and local minima,  so $a\le m+M$ and we are done.

Let $m_k$ be the probability that $X$ has a local minimum at index $k$. Using linearity of expectation we get,
\begin{align}\mathop{\mathbb {E}}[a(X)] &= \sum_{k=1}^n\mathop{\mathbb {P}}\left(\text{$X$ has a local minimum at index $k$}\right)\\&+\sum_{k=1}^n\mathop{\mathbb {P}}\left(\text{$X$ has a local maximum at index $k$}\right)\\&=2\sum_{k=1}^n m_k
\\&=2m_1+2m_n+2(n-2)m_2\\&=2\mathop{\mathbb {P}}(X_1<X_2)+2\mathop{\mathbb {P}}(X_{n-1}>X_n)\\&+2(n-2)\mathop{\mathbb {P}}(X_1>X_2<X_3)\\&=2\frac12+2\frac12\\&+2(n-2)\mathop{\mathbb{P}}\left(\min\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}=X_2\right)\\&=1+1+2(n-2)\frac13\\&=\frac{2n+2}{3}.\end{align}

This would be a great answer if you explained how one could mathematically prove $\alpha=$ (# local max) + (# local min).

@MikeEarnest I added some thoughts on that point.

This is a great answer :^)
